# global variables doesn't change

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have a problem with global variables in javascript.
Why latitude and longitude don't change?

```
var latitude;
var longitude;
  function initMap() {
    var reportDb = firebase.database().ref("Report");
    reportDb.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        longitude = childSnapshot.child("longitudine").val();
        latitude = childSnapshot.child("latitudine").val();
      });
    })window.alert(longitude);}
```

same problem with latitude

Comment: They do change. You are alerting them **before** they change.

Comment: You also have the problems that you missed out a `;` and **never call** `initMap`.

Comment: How I can use a changed values? I've used alert for test

Comment: There's a big yellow box at the top of the page with a link in it. Follow the link. Read the answers there.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

    var latitude;
    var longitude;

    var reportDb = firebase.database().ref("Report");
    reportDb.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        longitude = childSnapshot.child("longitudine").val();
        latitude = childSnapshot.child("latitudine").val();
        window.alert(longitude); // frist
      });
    });
    window.alert(longitude); //second
    </script>
why the frist work and second no?